# perl: match groups in multiple regexes

Tags: regex, perl

I'm wondering if there's there's some clever trick in perl that I don't know about to do the following:

```
my $re1 = qr/^(keyword\s+)(.*)$/;    
my $re2 = qr/^(otherkeyword\s+)(.*)$/;
my $re3 = qr/^(keyword_re3\s+)(.*)$/;

# there's around 20 expressions in reality, but I'll stick with 3 for the
# question...

my $testString = "otherkeyword xxxxx";

my ($keyword,$param) = $testString =~ /(?:$re1)|(?:$re2)|(?:$re3)/;
```

The problem of course, is the `$keyword` and `$param` are both blank because `$1` and `$2` refer to the capture groups in `$re1`.

I could loop through the regular expressions, and stop when I hit a match, but it seems more efficient to compile and run a single regex.   Of course, if I do that, I need a way to figure out what `$1` or `$2` are for the particular regex it matches.   I could try naming the capture groups, but these regex's are used to generate other regex's and it would complicate the program a lot.  I'm hoping there's a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Why not combine them into a single regexp? `/^((?:keyword|otherkeyword|keyword_re3)\s+)(.*)$/`

Comment: are all 20 the same except for the keyword?  if there are other differences, please show them.

Comment: The keywords are actually patterns as opposed to string literals, and the parameter regex can differ between different keywords.   To add to that, the regex's are defined in a different part of the code, for a slightly different purpose, and I was hoping to use the unmodified versions.   For now, I'm first testing against a joined regex, and if it matches, I'm looping through them to find which one hits.

Comment: Ok, I just read @ysth answer, and that's exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm going to switch to using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are significant differences between the patterns (i.e. capturing different numbers of things), you can work around having different capturing groups by doing:

```
my ($keyword,@param) = grep defined, $testString =~ /(?:$re1)|(?:$re2)|(?:$re3)/;
```

Otherwise, just make a single regex:

```
my @keyword = qw/keyword otherkeyword keyword_re3/;
my $keywords = join '|', map quotemeta, @keyword;
my $keyword_re = qr/^($keywords\s+)(.*)$/;
```

(Do you really want to capture the spaces?)

Comment: The `grep defined` looks exactly like what I was looking for -- thanks!  (and yes, I need to capture and preserve spaces -- it's actually a lot more complicated than that, as instead of just spaces, I have to capture comments as well, which can differ depending on what language I'm parsing... )

Comment: Although note `quotemeta` is for if your input is a literal, but it'll 'break' if you want to input regexes.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way by far is to use the *branch reset pattern* `(?| ... | ... |  ... )` which resets the numbering of the capture variables within each alternation branch

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;

my $re1 = qr/^(keyword\s+)(.*)$/;
my $re2 = qr/^(otherkeyword\s+)(.*)$/;
my $re3 = qr/^(keyword_re3\s+)(.*)$/;

my $testString = "otherkeyword xxxxx";
my ($keyword, $param) = $testString =~ /(?|(?:$re1)|(?:$re2)|(?:$re3))/;

print Dumper [ $keyword, $param ];
```

#### output

```
[
  'otherkeyword ',
  'xxxxx'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative here is to use named groups, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $re1 = qr/^(?:keyword\s+)(?<keyword>.*)/;
my $re2 = qr/^(?:otherkeyword\s+)(?<otherkeyword>.*)/;
my $re3 = qr/^(?:keyword_re3\s+)(?<keyword_re3>.*)/;

my $testString = "otherkeyword xxxxx";
if ($testString =~ /^(?:$re1|$re2|$re3)$/)
{
    for my $keyword (keys %+)
    {
        print "$keyword = $+{$keyword}\n";
    }
}
```

This prints out "otherkeyword = xxxxx" as you seem to want.